# Separate outlook getproperty into variables like message id, in-reply and so on

Tags: python, pandas, outlook

I working on some analytics for our email help line.  I can see the headers and everything that is in them, but I need to separate each header component into its own field/variable.  What is the best way to accomplish this.

here is the the code i currently have.

```
import win32com.client
import win32com
import pandas as pd

M_date = []
M_sender = []
M_sub = []
M_flag = []
M_cat = []
M_folder = []

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("outlook.application").GetNamespace("MAPI")


for i in range(0, 20):
    try:
        inbox = outlook.getdefaultfolder(6).folders[i]
        try:
            for message in inbox.items:
                try:
                    Folder = str(inbox) + " " + str(i)
                    Sender= message.sendername
                    Subject= message.subject
                    Dates= message.ReceivedTime
                    M_import = message.Importance
                    if message.FlagRequest == None :
                        Flag = ""
                    else:
                        Flag = message.FlagRequest
                    if message.Categories == None:  
                        cat = ""
                    else:
                        cat = message.Categories
                        msg = message.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x007D001F")
                        print(msg) #debug header

                    M_folder.append(Folder)
                    M_date.append(Dates.strftime("%b %d %Y %H:%M:"))
                    M_sender.append(Sender)
                    M_sub.append(Subject)
                    M_flag.append(Flag)
                    M_cat.append(cat)

                except:
                    pass
        except:
            pass
    except:
        pass

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'In folder': M_folder,
    'Date': M_date,
    'Sender': M_sender,
    'Subject': M_sub,
    'flags': M_flag,
    'Categrories': M_cat})

df.to_csv('email_data.csv', index=False)
```

Thanks

Comment: Is you problem (1) you do not know the format of a Transport Message Header so you cannot split it into lines or (2) having split it into lines, you do not know the format of the "To" line, for example?

Comment: As this is my first time working with headers,  I'm sure there is a lot I do not know about them.    If its just a format issue then  can you provide an example of how to work with this format.   - Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Transport headers is a string which contains properties and their values separated by ":". Basically you need to loop through all lines backwards. If the line starts with space or tab, append it to the previous line and delete the current line. Then loop through all lines and separate them into the header name (left of the first ":") and the header value (right of the first ":").

Answer (score 1):

I do not know Python so I cannot provide any code, but I can tell you about the format of the Transport Message Headers.  (I must learn Python, my son-in-law swears by it.)

The Transport Message Headers contain an indefinite number of lines separated by carriage return linefeed.  In VBA to access the individual lines, you would have something like:

```
Dim msgParts() As String
msgParts = Split(msg, vbCrLf)
```

If a line starts with one or more spaces and or horizontal tabs, it is a continuation of the previous line.  Replace all the spaces and tabs at the beginning of a continuation line with one space and append to the previous line.

A line, together with any continuation lines, starts “Xxxx: ”.  “Xxxx” will be “To” or “From” or any of the other specified identifiers or a private identifier.

The specification of the lines are RFCs (Request For Comments).  I would start with RFC 5321 and follow the references to the related RFCs.  Or perhaps I would not.

I have not looked at the RFCs for SMTP (Simple Mail Transfer Protocol) for many years.  My recollection is that they were once much simpler.  For example, my recollection is that the specification dealt with the continuations and then dealt with the combined line; this would have been standard practice when I was young.  I was looking at the specification for email addresses which seemed overly complicated with lots of CRLFs that I did not remember as being allowed within a line.  I finally realised that the specification for an email address allowed for a continuation line break between any two elements.  In my humble opinion, this made for an unnecessarily complex specification.  I would also expect the processing code to be slower since it would be attempting to solve two separate problems at the same time.

In the end, I gave up on the SMTP RFCs.  Partly because of the continuation line issue but mainly because they now handle a lot of specialised situations that are quite outside the needs of the simple emails I send and receive.  I decided it was easier to analyse the emails I had sent or received than attempt to simplify the specification down to my requirements.

My interest in looking at the Transport Message Headers was because I wanted to identify the other party of every email.  For every email in my Outlook folders, I was either the sender or I was one of the recipients.  If I was the sender, I wanted the first or only recipient.  If I was a recipient, I wanted the sender.  This proved difficult or impossible from the properties such as `To` and `From` because they usually contain display names.  The display names for myself, were every possible variation of my name.  If this issue is relevant to you, I am happy to share how I handled it.